# How to make changes in bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

Hi I have an assignment to complete and my teacher has asked me to make changes in my boot-loader so that when my system boots there is an option of "Welcome Sarah".

I have dual boot set up in my system, How should I do this?

Comment: Are you sure he meant "bootloader"? In general these questions are about showing a message when you log into a linux system from a login prompt.

Comment: -1 This is an assignment. Please show what you tried so far and how it failed.

Comment: Yes I am sure its not about the kernel log message because we have already done that.

Comment: I have till now added a background image on my grub but was unable to proceed further as I was confused where to proceed..@David Foerster

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

1. Find grub configuration file (can't tell exactly where to find it since you have not mentioned your version of Ubuntu, I would not tell even if you did)
2. Read the configuration file and locate the part where you want to make changes. I am sure you will find what you are looking for within this configuration file.
3. Make edits and save file (make a backup in case you don't want to get into more trouble)
4. Restart your PC.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu! this is not a complete answer rather shaky, to tell the OP do that somewhere I dunno where and you'll find that can lead to break the OS loading after that. Please give a more distinctive explanation as an answer.

Comment: 9 years ago when I wanted to change my bootloader options in Ubuntu I started exploring grub. I broke OS loading and recovered it through the backups I made before hand. It was a good experience learning about grub.

Comment: Hi I tried that but that did not work and it turns out that I need to design a bootloader and place it in a pen drive and when my system will boot through my bootable pendrive I would have do display my name on screen

Comment: Okay. Good luck with it.